# Trying to install tweepy to python in command prompt

Tags: python, api, twitter, tweepy

I tried running these commands:

```
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
```

However, I keep getting this error:

> 'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: Are you sure Python is installed on your system?

Comment: well now I'm not sure, I mean I do have the python shell and IDE but how do you mean?

Comment: Assuming you are running Windows, you need to add Python to your PATH. How to do it is explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15171157/python-is-not-recognised-as-an-internal-or-external-command) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17953124/python-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-why) for example.